# ASP.NET Core 6: copy external directory to the publish folder

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

How to copy the content of external directory to the publish folder when I do `dotnet publish` ?

I tried the following in the project config, but unfortunately this copies the content of `documents-templates` directory to the root of the `publish` directory, but I want the whole folder `documents-templates` to be copied with its contents.

Is there any way to set the destination folder name too ?

```
    <ItemGroup> 
        <Content Include="D:\Workspace\OtherProject\documents-templates\**"> 
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
        </Content> 
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I tried same thing, it works perfectly for me. check your project file if some other setting is interfering with this

Comment: if you tried it with folders in the same project it works fine with me too (the whole folder copied with its contents) , but I didn't understand why it is not working as expected with external folders (I got the internet files copied to the publish root folder)

Comment: Hmm.. I guess then you have to link those file or folder to make them copy at the of publish. I have done something same but that was for a file. I haven't tried for folder.

Comment: @Cloud-Lover Does my answer useful to u ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my local, and it works for me.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Parent Include="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Testimages\*.*" />
    
    <EmbeddedResource Include="@(Parent)">
      <Link>Resources\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```